# access denied to appdata folders in c#

Tags: c#, permissions, synchronization, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to sync my sticky notes from win7 machine to win7 machine using dropbox and then moving the data from the location (as far as i can tell you can't change the default sticky notes save location)

however when i use `File.Replace(source,destination);` I get an error (even if i run the program as admin)

> "Access to path is denied"

C:\Users\crash893\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes

I have full access to the machine but I would prefer a solution / hint that was programmatic in nature so I can let my friends do it with having to walk them through a bunch of steps

Comment: May be that file is being used by another process.

Comment: Are you able to copy the file manually in explorer? If this fails also you know it's because the file is in use.

Comment: Perhaps the target is readonly.\

Comment: it seems that it is in use. Do you know anyway to programmaticly check?